# "To show for" correct usage

Tags: grammar, phrases, idioms

Came across this sentence in a newspaper article.

"But as the months passed by quickly with little other than grand announcements and declarations to show **for**, the case for more hands at the wheel became compelling.

The "for" in the above sentence (after show) confuses me. 
If this is wrong usage, what would be more appropriate - to omit the "for" after "show" in this sentence? Or adding an "it" after "show for" to make it "show for it"?
Please give your enlightened views.

Answer (score 1):

The first few results from https://www.google.com/search?q=show+for+it suggest that the "it" in the phrase "show for it" is usually "work" or "effort" or something like that:

> I **worked** hard and have nothing to show for **it**.

In the referenced sentence you might want to use "them" instead of "it", because "them" would be referring to the (plural) months:

> But as **the months** passed by quickly with little (other than etc.) to show for **them**, ...

I'm not sure that using the plural is necessary, however, because I might say:

> I spent hours and have nothing to show for it
>
> I spent dollars and have nothing to show for it

Still I do agree with you: there is something missing after "show for".

Alternatively, change it to say something like,

> But as the months passed by quickly with **few results** except grand announcements and declarations, etc.

Comment: Thanks ChrisW. Still wondering if omitting "for" altogether will be acceptable.

Comment: You can omit the "for" because it is a conjunction that is not joining "show" to anything (hence the suggestion of "it").  But you can't just drop it either, because "show" needs to apply to something in the sentence.  I agree with @ChrisW, the editor of the newspaper should have replaced "show" with "few results" or some other clarifying clause.